# Show Woocommerce products by given IDs

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce shortcode to display products. I am using the code to display products

> [products limit="11" columns="1" ids="267386, 277401, 327621, 93036,
> 331573, 354114, 327602, 327600, 327598, 327603, 327599"]

But in the output (on page), the product id 93036 showing in first place, but it should display on fourth place. It should show on the first place. Can anyone let me know what I have to do to show products as they are placed?

Comment: I think that it is not possible using products shortcode with given product Ids... There is an `orderby` usable argument set to `menu_order`by default… You can choose between `menu_order`, `title`, `date`, `rand`, `price`, `popularity`, `rating`, or `id`... The `id` value will sort numerically products by their ids. The only way should be to use a custom shortcode with a custom query.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom query with a shortcode:

```
function custom_products_shortcode($atts) {
  $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
      'ids' => '',
  ), $atts);

  $product_ids = explode(',', $atts['ids']);
  $product_ids = array_map('trim', $product_ids);
  $product_ids = array_filter($product_ids);

  $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'product',
      'post__in' => $product_ids,
      'orderby' => 'post__in',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
  );

  $products = new WP_Query($args);

  ob_start();

  if ($products->have_posts()) {
      while ($products->have_posts()) {
          $products->the_post();
          wc_get_template_part('content', 'product');
      }
  }

  wp_reset_postdata();

  return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('custom_products', 'custom_products_shortcode');
```

and use

```
[custom_products ids="93036, 267386, 277401, 327621, 331573, 354114, 327602, 327600, 327598, 327603, 327599"]
```

Comment: Hi, Heidar Ammarloo!

You posted 9 answers in June that appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT), with *five* of these having comments that said that the answer didn't work. Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and continue to be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.